# Java reads ANSI file incorrectly

Tags: java, ansi, java.util.scanner

I tried to read an ANSI encoded Arabic file in Java using the following two way

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
           scanner = new Scanner(new File("test/input.txt"), "ISO-8859-6");

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String input =scanner.nextLine();
        processString(input);   
    }
```

I tried also to read with default encoding (i.e. I omitted the "ISO-8859-6")

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you verify that it is read incorrectly? I see nothing this code that suggests that.

Comment: @ JoachimSauer I used the debugging facility in eclipse. When I tested it with UTF-8 file I can see the Arabic string displayed correctly.

Comment: @Abdelwahed, So have you tried reading the file as "UTF-8"?  How do you know the file was written with "ISO-8859-6" encoding?

Comment: What is not being displayed correctly in Arabic?

Comment: @ PeterLawrey I use notepad++ to convert the encoding. When I encode it in UTF-8 and read from java using "UTF-8" encoding it works. However, setting the Arabic file encoding to ANSI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-6) and reading it from java as "ISO-8859-6" it doesn't work.

Comment: @JoePhilllips  all the contents of the file are not displayed correctly in the debugging

Comment: @abdelwahed, Are you sure ANSI doesn't refer to Windows-1252?

Comment: @PeterLawrey (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) Arabic characters are not part of them. I also tried it and no progress

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't problem with Eclipse that cannot display correctly characters, and not in Java ?

Comment: it worked using windows-1256 


    Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
               scanner = new Scanner(new File("test/input.txt"), "windows-1256");
    
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String input =scanner.nextLine();
            processString(input);   
        }

Comment: Can you answer the question yourself and then accept that answer. Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 public static void transform(File source, String srcEncoding, File target,       String tgtEncoding) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(source), Charset.forName(srcEncoding)));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(target), tgtEncoding));
        char[] buffer = new char[16384];
        int read;
        while ((read = br.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } finally {
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }`enter code here`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
       private static final String FILENAME = "/Users/jucepho/Desktop/ansi.txt";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            FileReader fr = null;
            try {
                fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String sCurrentLine;
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)
                        br.close();
                    if (fr != null)
                        fr.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

This file has this characters http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html